# Programmatically Finding, Correcting IDs in Dataframes with Different Column and Row Lengths

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames of differing lengths and widths. Both contain panel data on sites across several years, with each site having a unique ID code. However, these unique ID codes were altered for some sites between data frames. For example:

```
Year <- c(2006,2006,2006,2006)
Name <- as.character(c("A","B","C","D.B"))
Qtr.2 <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,40))
Code <- as.character(c(123,456,789,101))
DF1 <- data.frame(Year,Name,Qtr.2,Code,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Year2 <- c(2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2007)
Name2 <- as.character(c("A","B","C","E","D.B","D.A"))
Qtr.3 <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,11,40,20))
Code2 <- as.character(c("W33","456","789","121","W133","W111"))
Type <- as.character(c("Blue","Red","Red","Green","Blue","Red"))
DF2 <- data.frame(Year2,Name2,Qtr.3,Code2,Type,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> DF1
     Year Name Qtr.2 Code
   1 2006    A    14  123
   2 2006    B    32  456
   3 2006    C    62  789
   4 2006  D.B    40  101

> DF2
    Year2 Name2 Qtr.3 Code2 Type
  1  2007     A    14   W33  Blue
  2  2007     B    32   456   Red
  3  2007     C    62   789   Red
  4  2007     E    11   121 Green
  5  2007   D.B    40  W133  Blue
  6  2007   D.A    20  W111   Red
```

Here, site “A's” code has changed from “123” in DF1 to “W33” in DF2.
I am having trouble programmatically finding and converting the altered ID codes to match their prior ID code. In other words, I want to match names from DF1 to DF2, and replace "Code2" in DF2 with "Code" from DF1 when a matching name is discovered. My approach thus far has involved a rather convoluted padding and for loop process. However, I feel this must be a semiregular wrangling problem and there must be a simpler approach.

Ideally, my second DF would look as follows:

```
Year2_fixed <- c(2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2007)
Name2_fixed <- as.character(c("A","B","C","E","D.B","D.A"))
Qtr.3_fixed <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,11,40,20))
Code2_fixed <- as.character(c("123","456","789","121","101","W111"))
Type <- as.character(c("Blue","Red","Red","Green","Blue","Red"))
DF2_fixed <-data.frame(Year2_fixed,Name2_fixed,Qtr.3_fixed,Code2_fixed,Type,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    

> DF2_fixed

    Year2_fixed Name2_fixed Qtr.3_fixed Code2_fixed  Type
  1        2007           A          14         123  Blue
  2        2007           B          32         456   Red
  3        2007           C          62         789   Red
  4        2007           E          11         121 Green
  5        2007         D.B          40         101  Blue
  6        2007         D.A          20         W111  Red
```

I have done some looking but I haven't found a clear answer on OS that gets at this problem. It is possible I am not asking the question clearly enough in searches. Please point it out if it is out there, or let me know if I can clarify my question.

A few last points: I want to be able to perform an inner_join BY the code, preserving those observations that appear in both sets. I am providing a toy example, but, as is often the case, the true problem is too large to manually check these names.

**Edit**
As pointed out by others, stringAsFactors = FALSE has been added to prevent error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `match` command:

```
DF2 <- within(DF2, {
  ind <- match(Name2, DF1$Name)
  new_code <- DF1$Code[ind]
  Code_fixed <- ifelse(is.na(ind), as.character(Code2), as.character(new_code))
  rm(ind, new_code)
})
DF2
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use `dplyr::coalesce` along with `left_join` to get the desired result.

```
library(dplyr)

DF2 %>% left_join(select(DF1, Name, Code), by=c("Name2" = "Name")) %>%
  mutate(Code2 = coalesce(Code, Code2)) %>%
  select(-Code)

#   Year2 Name2 Qtr.3 Code2  Type
# 1  2007     A    14   123  Blue
# 2  2007     B    32   456   Red
# 3  2007     C    62   789   Red
# 4  2007     E    11   121 Green
# 5  2007   D.B    40   101  Blue
# 6  2007   D.A    20  W111   Red
```

**Note:** `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` has been added in OP's code to create data.frames, otherwise it would generate unnecessary warnings.

**Data:**

```
Year <- c(2006,2006,2006,2006)
Name <- as.character(c("A","B","C","D.B"))
Qtr.2 <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,40))
Code <- as.character(c(123,456,789,101))
DF1 <- data.frame(Year,Name,Qtr.2,Code, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Year2 <- c(2007,2007,2007,2007,2007,2007)
Name2 <- as.character(c("A","B","C","E","D.B","D.A"))
Qtr.3 <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,11,40,20))
Code2 <- as.character(c("W33","456","789","121","W133","W111"))
Type <- as.character(c("Blue","Red","Red","Green","Blue","Red"))
DF2 <- data.frame(Year2,Name2,Qtr.3,Code2,Type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```